# How can I add a longPressAction to a NavigationButton without overwriting the default tap behavior?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to add a long press using the .longPressAction() func to the NavigationButton. It only recognizes the long press and ignores the default behavior.

I've tried using a SimultaneousGesture but NavigationButton doesn't expose its tap gesture. Creating my own tap gesture won't work because I need to be able to push to a new View.

```swift
NavigationButton(destination: IssueDetail(issue: issue), 
onTrigger: { return self.issue.instructions != nil }) {
    IssueCardBody(issue: issue)
        .longPressAction({ print("pressed") })
}
```

It will print "pressed" but won't push to the new View.

Comment: Same question, I have the problem with both NavigationLink and the scroll in a list.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use the following trick:

```
@State var isTapped = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination:  Text("Your Detail view"), isActive: $isTapped) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            Text("Your card")
                .onTapGesture { self.isTapped.toggle() }
                .onLongPressGesture { print("pressed") }
        }
    }
 }
```